# Change Label into Textbox/Button

Tags: java, swt

I would like to create a dialog window that shows a user's profile (such as name, avatar, sex, etc.) in a visually pleasing way by using labels that contain the relevant information. At the same time, I would like to show an edit button that transforms the labels into textboxes or buttons allowing the name or avatar to be changed.

How can I realize this with SWT? What would be the best strategy to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Text` and then set `setEditable(boolean)` to enable/disable editing of the text box from the `SWT.Selection` `Listener` of the `Button`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    // Create a read-only text field
    final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setEditable(false);
    text.setText("Some text here");

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Change");
    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            text.setEditable(!text.getEditable());
        }
    });

    shell.open();
    shell.pack();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a `StackLayout` and have two versions of the same UI (or just parts of it) and switch between them when the button is pressed.

Comment: The editable text fields aren't really what I was looking for as I am trying to get rid of the "form" look and feel of the dialog.

Thanks for the tip with the StackLayout though, I didn't even consider that. This seems like the perfect solution for me!

Comment: @pfolta Well, then you'll either have to use the `StackLayout` idea or dispose/add widgets dynamically.